How to Connect an Xbox Controller to a Windows 11 Google Cloud Virtual Machine?
I recently set up a gaming virtual machine (VM) on Google Cloud Platform for gaming, but I’m struggling with getting my Xbox One Series X/S controller to be detected directly by the VM. Here is the tutorial I followed:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNZ6NhPJYfA&ab_channel=JohnRagone
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
VM Setup:
Created a VM instance on Google Cloud using the NVIDIA Gaming PC (Windows Server 2019) option from the Google Cloud Marketplace.
Configured the VM with NVIDIA T4 GPUs (via quota increase) and an SSD persistent disk.
Opened necessary ports for Moonlight and connected to the VM initially through Remote Desktop.
Controller Connection:
My controller is connected to my local Windows 11 machine via USB/Bluetooth.
I’ve used Parsec to enable controller input, but it’s unreliable since the controller randomly disconnects during use.
What I’m Trying to Achieve:
I want the VM to directly recognize my Xbox controller without relying on Parsec or any other third-party tools. Ideally, I’d like a solution involving native Windows configurations or settings in Google Cloud.
Has anyone successfully set up controller detection on a Google Cloud VM without third-party software? Any tips or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Go to VM settings then click Add New Device > PCI device > Add. Select your USB controller from the dropdown menu using the correct ID. Power on the virtual machine. Check the devices in the guest OS.
